# About plugin script

Tags: wordpress, customization

Easy digital download is already installed on my site

i need a pluging for bulk edit prices on my products. Can anybody provide a guid to create script and creating this plugin for my products

Comment: by bulk edit do you mean all of the products get increase price by 20% or reduced by 5 ,something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly from the dabase

```
UPDATE your_product_table SET product_price = (product_price * 2)
```

Basically increase the product price by 2 times.

Just set the proper table and row names and it should work,and ofcourse fix the equasion to your liking